# is $2 + e^xy + xe^xy + (xe^x + 4)y' = 0$ a first order linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you solve this ODE by using the formula for first order linear ODE, not exact ODE?
$$2 + e^xy + xe^xy + (xe^x + 4)y' = 0$$
Can anybody explain the difference between exact ODE and first order linear ODE?
Thanks!

Comment: This DE is linear and exact

Comment: 100%? I solved it using the formula for first order linear ODE and got the same answer but our professor posted a solution using exact ODE only

Comment: You van solve it both ways <ith exctness or as a first order linar DE